# discord.py: Adding role to user throws error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need help with a bot event. Whenever I add the code, it gives me this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Tragic-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 20, in on_member_join
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

Here is the code:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = client.get_guild(999108955437551666)
    channel = guild.get_channel(999108956020555798)
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=999356633023000586)   
    
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
    await channel.send(f'Hello, {member.mention} :partying_face:! Welcome to Tragic Tech! Make sure to read the rules so you wont get banned right away!')
```

If anyone could help me that would be great. This happens on replit.com, and I am new so any help is great. Thanks!

Comment: What is a `client`? Can you show the definition of its type?

Comment: @wkl it's `commands.Bot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error already tells you: `'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_roles'` -> `Bot.add_roles()` doesn't exist. But what exists is `Member.add_roles()`.

So, your code would look like that:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = client.get_guild(999108955437551666)
    channel = guild.get_channel(999108956020555798)
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=999356633023000586)   
    
    # add_roles() is a method of `discord.Member`
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await channel.send('your message')
```

---

###### References:

- [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20member#discord.Member)
- [`Member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20member#discord.Member.add_roles)